# How do you handle shoes on a character you want to animate?

Tags: animation, texture-baking

I have this model that I wish to rig and animate, and I want the character to wear shoes. At first I thought I could just create a model that has no feet; it just has shoes attached to it (a little cheat). My original plan was to separate the shoes from the model (mint green), use these shoe models I downloaded (in the more yellow green) and bake the textures onto my shoes. I haven't had any experience with baking yet, so I don't know if this would be too complicated or not. Is there an easier way to keep shoes attached to a character through parenting and rigging or would my baking idea work? If any knows of any tutorials that'd be great. I've only seen videos on how to model shoes so far.

[image])

Comment: I don't understand what is your issue here. You wonder what would work? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: both solutions are ok, you can use the current feet and bake the shoes, or use the shoes themselves. If the shoes are high-poly though, you'd better use the first solution, or make a low-poly version